# How can i print an session array's value based on array having a variable as key in laravel blade

Tags: arrays, laravel, session

I have a session array as seen below.  How can i print the vendor of the 1st item in this example?

```
[items] => Array
    (
        [00kAJ000001WSxAYAW] => Array
            (
                [itemName] => Something
                [quantity] => 1
                [price] => $2,400.00
                [vendor] => facebook
                [orderDate] => 
                [deliveryDate] => 
                [poNumber] => 
                [delayNotes] => 
            )

        [00kAJ000001WSxEYAW] => Array
            (
                [itemName] => SomeOtherThing
                [quantity] => 1
                [price] => $5.00
                [vendor] => 
                [orderDate] => 
                [deliveryDate] => 
                [poNumber] => 
                [delayNotes] => 
            )

    )
```

if i do:

```
{{session('items.00kAJ000001WSxAYAW.vendor') ?? 'empty'}}
```

I get the expected result: "facebook"

how would i get that same result if the id was a variable?

```
{{session('items.$itemData->Id.vendor') ?? 'empty'}}
```

My result for this is "empty"

Answer (score 0):

{{session('items')["{$itemData->Id}"]['vendor'] ?? 'empty'}}